# How to configure SMTP Gmail in instance

Tags: windows, smtp

I install Vtiger CRM in a Windows instance. In others installation  the next parameters work fine:

```
ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 
xxx@gmail.com          -- gmail account
xxxx                   -- password
```

The error message is : Mail could not be sent

The firewall rule is created for port 465 and Windows Firewall have the inbound and outbound rules.

Comment: check if your google account is allowing you to connect from untrusted sources

Comment: Thanks !!! This option was disabled.